# How to weave two NumPy arrays together

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two NumPy arrays, both with a shape of (N, 3). Each array has the same length, but they are randomly generated so the length varies on each run. I want to iterate through each index of both arrays and weave them together. For example, if N=2, it should look like this:

```
(((1,2,3), (4,5,6)), ((7,8,9), (10,11,12)))
```

I would also need to convert them to a string. How could I format the arrays and convert them?

Comment: `str(a)` ? is one way you can make a string ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip function to iterate through the indices of both arrays and weave them together. Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates how to achieve this:

```
import numpy as np

# Generate two arrays with shape (N, 3)
N = 2
array1 = np.random.rand(N, 3)
array2 = np.random.rand(N, 3)

# Weave the two arrays together using zip
weaved_array = list(zip(array1, array2))

# Convert the weaved array to a string
weaved_string = str(weaved_array)

# Print the weaved string
print(weaved_string)
```

This will output a string that looks like this:

[((array1[0]), (array2[0])), ((array1[1]), (array2[1]))]

Note that the arrays are wrapped in parentheses and the weaved array is wrapped in square brackets. If you want a slightly different format, you can modify the str function call accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hstack` with `ravel` to acheive weaved 1D array. Then you can convert each element into char and join to form a string.

```
N = 2
a= np.random.rand(N, 3) # np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = np.random.rand(N, 3) # np.array([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
# Stack horizontally and ravel to get weaved 1D array
w = np.hstack((a,b)).ravel()
# array([ 1,  2,  3,  7,  8,  9,  4,  5,  6, 10, 11, 12])
# Convert each element to character
sw = np.char.mod('%i',w)
# join with blank delimiter to get string
res = ''.join(sw)
```